# Ignore restrictions for truck over 20 ton

Tags: here-api

I use same request [http://fleet.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?app_id={app_id}&app_code={app_code}&mode=truck;fastest;traffic:disabled&language=en-GB&representation=overview&metricSystem=metric&routeattributes=wp,sc,sm,sh,bb,lg,no,shape&legattributes=wp,mn,li,le,tt&maneuverattributes=po,sh,tt,le,ti,li,pt,pl,rn,nr,di&linkattributes=sh,le,sl,ds,tr&trailersCount=0&alternatives=0&currency=EUR&trailerType=2&vehicleNumberAxles=2&trailerNumberAxles=3&hybrid=0&height=4m&trailerHeight=400&vehicleWeight=8000&limitedWeight=20t&width=225&length=3&disabledEquipped=0&minimalPollution=0&hov=0&passengersCount=1&commercial=1&heightAbove1stAxle=300&fuelType=Diesel&detail=1&rollup=none,country;tollsys&emissionType=5&shippedhazardousgoods=0&waypoint0=geo!41.3260846,2.1408677&waypoint1=geo!41.3566442,2.0946016](http://fleet.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?app_id=%7Bapp_id%7D&app_code=%7Bapp_code%7D&mode=truck;fastest;traffic:disabled&language=en-GB&representation=overview&metricSystem=metric&routeattributes=wp,sc,sm,sh,bb,lg,no,shape&legattributes=wp,mn,li,le,tt&maneuverattributes=po,sh,tt,le,ti,li,pt,pl,rn,nr,di&linkattributes=sh,le,sl,ds,tr&trailersCount=0&alternatives=0&currency=EUR&trailerType=2&vehicleNumberAxles=2&trailerNumberAxles=3&hybrid=0&height=4m&trailerHeight=400&vehicleWeight=8000&limitedWeight=20t&width=225&length=3&disabledEquipped=0&minimalPollution=0&hov=0&passengersCount=1&commercial=1&heightAbove1stAxle=300&fuelType=Diesel&detail=1&rollup=none,country;tollsys&emissionType=5&shippedhazardousgoods=0&waypoint0=geo!41.3260846,2.1408677&waypoint1=geo!41.3566442,2.0946016)

How can I get route and cost of road  avoiding of restrictions for truck with weight over 20t?

Thank for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, please use the latest URL for the request.`https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json?apikey={{RESTapiKey}}...`
If you want to avoid restrictions for trucks, add the parameter `truckRestrictionPenalty` and set the value to `soft`.

The route violating truck restrictions is indicated in the response with dedicated route and maneuver notes. The route with the note of the type violation and the text truckRestriction may be traveled at your own responsibility. While driving on such route,  extra care has to be taken as it may result in a vehicle or a road infrastructure damage.

Comment: Thank for help. I found this documentation for URL https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json?* , but I didn't found description of parameter truckRestrictionPenalty

Comment: You can find the parameter under the Routing v7 API. 
https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/resource-calculate-route.html